# SQL & FIND_IN_SET for filtering

Tags: php, sql, ajax

On the main page I have a list of establishments, which you can filter with location, name and services provided by that establishment.
I have SQL table, which has list of establishments with numeric definition of services provided:

```
id | name            | location | services
1  | Establishment 1 | Florida  | 2,5
2  | Establishment 2 | New York | 1,3,5
```

On the main page services are supposed to be filtered by checking checkboxes.

**I'm looking for SQL query which will filter results based on selected services** (eg if user selected service 5 - it will show both results from the table above, but if user selects services 5 and 1 - only service with id 2, if selects 5 and 4 - no results).

I found out that FIND_IN_SET might work, but it seems that it doesn't work if user selects more than one service:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, t.services) > 0
```

? - bind input, which is sent by POST AJAX as concatenation of selected services divided by comas - eg. services = "1,3,4".

Comment: You cant do that. You should split the input by comma and use FIND_IN_SET for each of them joined by AND/OR. However, this is very inefficient way of sql filtering, so you should really store `services` values in a second table (one value => one row). Then, you can join that table and filter it using standard equality operands.

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not be storing multiple values in a single column -- they should be in separate rows in  a junction/association table.  Just as ad is storing numbers as strings!

Comment: Hi, thanks for you replies. For your proposed solution I have to build imploding SQL query with many "if" statements. Like this one - http://forums.devshed.com/php-development/965676-filter-mysql-table-using-html-checkboxes-post2947379.html?s=f3712d08eefe79c4ddcf77944b3d4ff7#post2947379 And then wondering whether it still worth doing it, as my assumption that performance of such query would be even worse, then looking into one cell and finding matching services

Answer (score 0):

You can try `REGEXP` :

Check this:

```
SELECT * FROM testtbl t WHERE t.services REGEXP '(^|,)(1|3|4)(,|$)'
```

You need to pass your comma separated value in this form =>`1|3|4`

Comment: Thanks Shail, but this query checks whether row contains any of passed values. E.g. '(^|,)(1|3|4)(,|$)' selects services with 1|5|7, as those have "1" in common. I would like to select rows which have all of 1|3|4.